# react native change hookState but component does not re-render

Tags: react-native, hook

I am new in React native developer

Im using hook to set the user info(avatar + name). Like below

[image: register hook]

[image: define component]

[image: useState]

But after setUserAvt and setUserName, i didnt see the RecentlyUserHeader re-render, it's only change when i press cmd+S to save code. Can anyone help me know the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using useEffect with an empty dependency array means that the code inside only executes once when component mounts. You call your api when your component mounts but you also set your navigation options here. So, this code also executes "once". But it should react the data change after you get your data and re-render. Try this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   _getMasterInfoApi()
}, [])



React.useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
          headerTitle: props => <RecentlyUserHeader {...props, userAvt, userName} />
          ... you get the idea
    })
  }, [userAvt, userName])
```